# How to restore default Dell laptop screen brightness level?

Tags: ubuntu, power-management, dell-inspiron, lcd, brightness

Ubuntu 16.04 on Dell Inspiron laptop. Laptop screen brightness somehow abruptly diminished, I can adjust it manually via `System settings > Brightness & Lock`, though. But what is the default screen brightness level value? It was fully acceptable. How to restore (reset) default screen brightness level? `intel_backlight`